# Predict votes of future comments

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, text-mining

I have a database with a lot of comments, each comment has a vote, a vote can be positive or negative. ex : -2, -5, -90, +45, +20...

So based on this training dataset I want to predict votes of future comments. How is it possible ? Thank you in advance

Comment: You'l get more specific answers if you would explain what you have already tried. Right now your question is very broad and answer would be: use a regression model to train on the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hoping to process the text of the comments this is definitely possible. Just NLP training and a single output score.

But this might be more machinery than you're looking for? If you have more data on the comments this will be do-able without a neural net.